# Python urllib2 request blinking cursor no response

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract data from BBB but I get no response. I don't get any error messages, just a blinking cursor. Is it my regex that is the issue? Also, if you see anything that I can improve on in terms of efficiency or coding style, I 
am open to your advice!

Here is the code:

```
import urllib2
import re

print "Enter an industry keyword."
print "Example: florists, construction, tiles"

keyword = raw_input('> ')

print "How many pages to dig through BBB?"
total_pages = raw_input('> ')

print "Working..."

page_number = 1
address_list = []

url = 'https://www.bbb.org/search/?type=category&input=' + keyword + '&filter=business&page=' + str(page_number)

req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()

address_pattern = r'<address>(.*?)<\/address>'

while page_number <= total_pages:

    business_address = re.findall(address_pattern,str(respData))

    for each in business_address:
        address_list.append(each)

    page_number += 1

for each in address_list:
    print each

print "\n Save to text file? Hit ENTER if so.\n"
raw_input('>')

file = open('export.txt','w')

for each in address_list:
    file.write('%r \n' % each)

file.close()

print 'File saved!'
```

**EDITED, but still don't get any results:**

```
import urllib2
import re

print "Enter an industry keyword."
print "Example: florists, construction, tiles"

keyword = raw_input('> ')

print "How many pages to dig through BBB?"
total_pages = int(raw_input('> '))

print "Working..."

page_number = 1
address_list = []

for page_number in range(1,total_pages):

    url = 'https://www.bbb.org/search/?type=category&input=' + keyword + '&filter=business&page=' + str(page_number)

    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()

    address_pattern = r'<address>(.*?)<\/address>'

    business_address = re.findall(address_pattern,respData)

    address_list.extend(business_address)

for each in address_list:
    print each

print "\n Save to text file? Hit ENTER if so.\n"
raw_input('>')

file = open('export.txt','w')

for each in address_list:
    file.write('%r \n' % each)

file.close()

print 'File saved!'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `total_pages` using `int` and use range instead of your while loop:

```
total_pages = int(raw_input('> '))
...............

for page_number in range(2, total_pages+1):
```

That will fix your issue but the loop is redundant, you use the same `respData` and `address_pattern` in the loop so you will keep adding the same thing repeatedly, if you want to crawl multiple pages you need to move the urllib code inside the for loop so you crawl using each `page_number`:

```
for page_number in range(1, total_pages):
    url = 'https://www.bbb.org/search/?type=category&input=' + keyword + '&filter=business&page=' + str(page_number)
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()

    business_address = re.findall(address_pattern, respData)
    # use extend to add the data from findall
    address_list.extend(business_address)
```

`respData` is also already a string so you don't need to call `str` on it, also using [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) can simplify your code further:

```
import requests

for page_number in range(1,total_pages):
    url = 'https://www.bbb.org/search/?type=category&input=' + keyword + '&filter=business&page=' + str(page_number)
    respData = requests.get(url).content
    business_address = re.findall(address_pattern,str(respData))
    address_list.extend(business_address)
```

Comment: No worries, make sure you move the code in the loop as in the second part of the answer if you want to crawl multiple pages, as it stands you only scrape page_number 1

Comment: Yep, they would need to have it installed alright, if you were creating a package you could make it a requirement

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense! Thank you. Also I edited the code so that the urllib2 code is now inside the for loop, but for some reason now it just skips to asking to save the file. I will edit my original post and put what I have so far, maybe I'm missing something again.

Comment: I will post the full code to pastebin, it works fine for me http://pastebin.com/SA3q2Rw6

Comment: Oh you used requests. Okay I guess I'm just better off using that instead. Just wanted to see the results with urllib2 as well. Thank you for the pastebin link :)

Comment: I used urllib aso as per the pastebin link,  both are working for me

Comment: Hey Padraic, I tried your pastebin code, and I still get nothing. Sorry to bother, just don't know what to do. I tried using requests completely instead of urllib as well (get content), but get an openssl error. I tried your code and get an "urllib2 not defined error". Tried going around that by adding import urllib2, still nothing.

Comment: You need to add the imports, I just added the logic, the openssl was an error or warning?

Comment: The openssl was a warning (insecureplatformwarning)

Comment: Yes just a warning, but it did not output any results

Comment: That just means your findall is wrong or else your search term, do it in a browser first and make sure you get a match for the keyword

Comment: Thank you :) will try it

Answer (score 1):

The main issue I see in your code, that is causing the infinite loop is that `total_pages` is defined as a string in lines -

```
total_pages = raw_input('> ')
```

But `page_number` is defined as an int.

Hence , the while loop -

```
while page_number <= total_pages:
```

would not end unless some exception occurs from within it, since `str` is always larger than `int` in Python 2.x .

You would most probably need to convert the `raw_input()` to `int()` since you are only using `total_pages` in the condition in the while loop. Example -

```
total_pages = int(raw_input('> '))
```

I have not checked whether the rest of your logic is correct or not, but I believe the above is the reason you are getting the infinite loop.